# How did Skylab's "space shower" work?

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle, skylab, hygiene

Skylab had a shower to help the astronauts bathe.

- How did the astronauts get wet?  (Fixed nozzle, movable showerhead, etc.; volume of water)
- How did they get themselves dry?
- How did they contain and collect the remaining water?
- What was the official assessment of the system?  (Please quote *official* sources)

Related: [Is there a better way for astronauts to bathe?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16696/26446)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [schematic](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740024203.pdf) of the shower system.

[image]

A description from [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750002066.pdf).

> This is an enclosure which uses continuous airflow as a gravity
>   substitute to move the water over the crewman. A 6-pound capacity
>   water bottle is filled from the waste management compartment water
>   heater, pressurized with nitrogen, and attached to the grid ceiling at
>   the shower location. The nitrogen gas pressurant  expels water from
>   the bottle through a transfer hose and a crew- operated hand-held
>   spray nozzle. A soap dispenser provides the crewman with 8 milliliters
>   of liquid soap for each shower. During the shower this dispenser
>   fastens to the ceiling with Velcro. A suction head removes water from
>   the crewman and the shower interior. The suction head is connected
>   by hoses to the centrifugal separator, which deposits the waste  water
>   into a collection bag. A blower pulls the air from the separator
>   through a hydrophobic filter that protects the blower.

Jack Lousma commented in a official [document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20090026561.pdf) recording the results of a project which sought to learn from Skylab experience to help the ISS design:

> You had to mix water in a 3-quart container – so much hot, so much
>   cold.  You had soap that was probably better used in a veterinary
>   practice, because it made you itch.  We sprayed water on ourselves
>   with a sprayer and then had to vacuum it off with a suction device.
>
> One thing worth noting is that we were in this low-pressure
>   environment and so whenever you got that water on you and went to dry
>   yourself off, it got extremely cold because it was evaporating so
>   rapidly.  It took a lot of vacuuming to get all of the water out from
>   inside of cylinder.  You had to use a lot of towels to get dry. 
>   During our mission we usually just took sponge baths every night with
>   a washcloth and a towel.

Jerry Carr:

> Well, I took a shower every 10 days whether I needed it or not.  But I
>   found the shower to be quite refreshing and I enjoyed it.  The only
>   downside was that it just took too doggone long to do all that stuff. 
>   So if they can find a way to take a shower a little more quickly,
>   they’d be on the right track.

Owen Garriot:

> The average time for a shower was about 1 hour.  You can clean up with
>   a wash cloth in 10 minutes or less.  To me, I would skip the whole
>   thing.  You don’t need a shower, even on ISS.

Their comments are summed up in the NASA [document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760022256.pdf) "Skylab Lessons Learned as Applicable to a Large Space Station" as

> It worked in orbit, but, to the surprise of  the author,  many of the
>   astronauts did  not feel it was required nor  needed. Because of the
>   time to operate and clean up,  few of the crewmen thought it worth the
>   effort. Future  systems should be simpler to operate.

Comment: This sounds terrifying-- can't you really easily drown in space? So if for any reason the air stopped, you'd asphyxiate fairly quickly if the water built up on your face.

Comment: At least in the shower you could wipe the water off your face.  Not like in a space suit....

Comment: Okay, you're [entirely correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOIW6IgTN6U) I could've sworn water would behave differently. Maybe the scenario I'm thinking of was from that question where there's a swimmer in a "0g pool".

Comment: The same guy in that video is the one who had the spacesuit failure that was filling his helmet up with water. Now that is a nightmare scenario.